# Problema com Subscribe quando o retorno é um único Objeto

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em angular 6 e estou tendo um problema quando eu faco o Subscribe no método que retorna um único objeto na requisição HTTP.

Por exemplo, fazendo esta requisição pelo meu componente:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    const empresaId = this.route.snapshot.params['empresaId']
    this.empresaService.getEmpresa(empresaId).subscribe(resp => this.empresa = resp)

    console.log(this.empresa)
  }
```

O meu objeto empresa fica `undefined`, porém se eu coloco um console log dentro do subscribe estou retornando meu json normalmente

Observei um detalhe. Caso eu crie um método tipo:

```
 obterEmpresa() {
    const empresaId = this.route.snapshot.params['empresaId']
    this.empresaService.getEmpresa(empresaId).subscribe(resp => this.empresa = resp)

    console.log(this.empresa)
  }
```

E coloco este método no evento do botão, no primeiro clique retorna `undefined`. Porém, no segundo clique o objeto é preenchido normalmente com a resposta.

Este problema estou tendo somente quando o retorno é um único objeto. Quando é um array, funciona normalmente.

Caso precise do meu método do service, aí está ele:

```
 getEmpresa(id: number): Observable<Empresa> {
    return this.http.get<Empresa>(`${URI}/empresa/${id}`)
  }
```

Comment: isto não e um problema e sim o comportamento esperado. Pelo http ser assíncrono o objeto só terá valor dentro do Subscribe.

Comment: Ola Eduardo, desculpa é que sou novato em desenvolvimento web, e no caso para eu deixar o objeto neste caso o this.empesa  com valor para todo o escopo como seria?

Comment: As propriedades de um componente tem o escopo do componente.Do jeito que vc fez this,empresa terá o valor do retorno do http quando esta request for bem sucedida.

Comment: Pra ver op valor da sua resposta vc pode fazer assim:  this.empresaService.getEmpresa(empresaId).subscribe(resp =>console.log(resp))

Answer (score 4):

Isso é normal cara, acontece por que a requisição que você está fazendo é assíncrona. Se você quiser dar um `console.log()` tente algo como.

```
obterEmpresa() {
    const empresaId = this.route.snapshot.params['empresaId']
    this.empresaService.getEmpresa(empresaId).subscribe(resp =>
    {
      this.empresa = resp;
      console.log(this.empresa);
    })
  }
```

Dessa maneira quando a requisição que você fez ao servidor for resolvida o subscribe vai ser executado e o console.log irá funcionar.